# Connecting 2 Textboxes values temporarily

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to create 2 Textboxes (txt1, txt2) and when I write in txt1 then txt2 should reflect the same text what i typed in txt1. For ex. When we create a new Solution in Visual Studio Professional, what name we give to Project, same name appears for Solution. But if we edit solution name, link between the 2 textboxes breaks.
I do have some idea about it, to do it with textChange event or in fact many similar events, but not sure that they are the best methods.
I am using Winforms, C# 4.0, Visual Studio 2010 (if this info matters)
If my question is not clear, just make a comment I will try to elaborate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, so thought to post it here

```
txt1_TextChanged(obje....)
{
   txt2.Text = txt1.Text;
}

txt2_TextChanged(objec...)
{
   if(txt2.Focused)
   {
      txt1.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(txt1_TextChanged);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding an event handler for txt1_TextChanged and txt2_KeyPress.

txt1_TextChanged would assign txt2.Text: `txt2.Text = "c:\" + txt1.Text;`

txt2_KeyPress would unsubscribe txt1_TextChanged: `txt1.TextChanged -= txt1_TextChanged;`.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned the solution in my problem I think :-)

Comment: it will just/only type the first letter in txt2.

Comment: but why you want to go for keypress, i know it will work but why will it work better. Well you can see my solution, i posted it here. will be happy to have comments

Answer (score 0):

With the given definition of the requirement, adding TextChanged EventHandlers is the way to go.

```
private void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt2.Text = txt1.Text;
}

private void txt2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Text = txt2.Text;
}
```

Comment: @rapsalands, in such situations it is a good practice to upvote the answers that you found useful and accept one of them, it encourages the answerers to take your other (future) questions seriously.

Comment: try to go through my question once again. It is not what I was looking for. I wrote "it worked" because the concept was same. But still will follow you. thanks for help.